# bot not returning speech

Tags: python, if-statement, chatbot

I'm trying to have an 'if statement' change the response "barnaby" (name of the bot program) gives when the user says hello, hey, hi, hayo or yo, the bot will respond with 'whats up'. But when I tested it it didn't respond, instead, it didn't say anything, and rather just let the user keep typing. I've included some code:

```
you = 'yes'

inpt = 'jifo3'

def run():

  inpt = 'jifo3'

  you = 'yes'
  
  if inpt == 'jifo3':
    
    print("Hello there. I'm barnaby, the sub-par chatbot.")

  while True:
    
    if you == 'yes':
      
      inpt = input()
      
      you = 'no'
      
    if you == 'no':
          
      respond()
          
      you = 'yes'

def respond():
  
  if inpt == 'hi' or inpt == 'hello' or inpt == 'hey' or inpt == 'hayo' or inpt == 'yo':
    
    print('whats up?')
      
  else:
    
    print('I dont understand. Please try something more simple like "Hi" or "Hello"')

run()
```

Comment: You need to a `__main__` block https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that any changes to the variable inpt that happen to it inside of run()  does not change the value of inpt outside of that function, so input is always 'jifo3' in respond(), which is why  the chatbot never responds. The simplest solution would probably be to combine respond() and run() into one method. [This website](https://iq.opengenus.org/pass-by-reference-python/) explains more about this problem in case you need more info.

```
you = 'yes'

inpt = 'jifo3'

def run():

  inpt = 'jifo3'

  you = 'yes'
  
  if inpt == 'jifo3':
    
    print("Hello there. I'm barnaby, the sub-par chatbot.")

  while True:
    
    if you == 'yes':
      
      inpt = input("Please say something: ")
      you = 'no'
      
    if you == 'no':
      if inpt == "hi" or inpt == 'hello' or inpt == 'hey' or inpt == 'hayo' or inpt == 'yo':
    
        print('whats up?')
      
      else:
    
        print('I dont understand. Please try something more simple like "Hi" or "Hello"')
          
      you = 'yes'
run()
```